# The unit ball is not auto similar.

Tags: reference-request, fractals

I want read a prove that the unit ball $B$ is not auto similar. I mean that there is not similarities $f_1,...,f_n$ with contracting constants <1, such that
$$B=\bigcup_{i=1}^n f_i[B] $$

Anyone knows where to find this proof?

Thanks!

Comment: I like your comment as a proof. Thanks. If you like, write it as an answer.

Comment: Done! I think I improved it a bit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false in $\mathbb R$ and many other metric spaces as well. So let's assume we're working in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space for $n>1$.

As is well known, a circle in the plane is uniquely determined by three points and a sphere in space by four points.  More generally, an $n-1$-sphere in ${\mathbb R}^n$ is uniquely determined by finitely many points ($n+1$, I believe). As a result, $f_i(B)$ can only contain $n$ points of $B$; otherwise it would contain the entire boundary of $B$ contradicting that $f_i$ is a contraction.

Thus,
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^m f_i(B)$$
can contain at most finitely many points of the boundary of $B$.